# Finding a person with no Activity before a certain date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My problem here is to find a non-active person that didn't have any activity since or before Dec-01-2011.

```
PersonID   Activity
----------------------
Alvin      Jan-08-2010
Alvin      Mar-11-2011
Alvin      Feb-11-2015
Simon      Nov-20-2010
Simon      Jan-23-2011
Simon      Jul-03-2011
Simon      Nov-04-2011
Theodore   Mar-09-2010
Theodore   Oct-08-2013
Dave       Aug-13-2012
Dave       Jun-01-2014
Dave       Apr-23-2015
Ian        Aug-09-2010
Ian        Nov-30-2010
Ian        Jan-25-2011
Ian        Mar-14-2011
Clare      Sep-03-2011
Clare      Aug-15-2014
Gale       Jun-18-2010
Gale       Dec-03-2010
```

Output:

```
PersonID   Activity
----------------------
Simon      Nov-20-2010
Simon      Jan-23-2011
Simon      Jul-03-2011
Simon      Jul-04-2011
Ian        Aug-09-2010
Ian        Nov-30-2010
Ian        Jan-25-2011
Ian        Mar-14-2011
Gale       Jun-18-2010
Gale       Dec-03-2010
```

Desired Output:

```
PersonID 
--------- 
Simon
Ian
Gale
```

The desired Result is preferred as it will tell me the person who is not active.

Comment: I think you should use SELECT DISTINCT PersonID in your select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` will do the trick:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/690fdc/1/0)

```
SELECT PersonID
FROM tbl
GROUP BY PersonID
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Activity > '20111201' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head.. something like this should do it

```
SELECT PersonID
FROM TableName
GROUP BY PersonID
HAVING MAX(Activity) <= '2011-12-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter out all entries first using your criteria, then apply a `DISTINCT` on your result set

```
SELECT DISTINCT PersonID
FROM YourTableName
WHERE Activity <= 'Dec-01-2011'
```